# Getting the first occurrence of group of rows

Tags: oracle

Am having a case where I have transaction and this transaction consists of several steps. I want to return the first occurrence of this transaction, for example:

```
Trn Loc step

111 0   1

111 0   2

111 0   3

222 3   1

222 3   2

333 5   1

333 5   2

333 5   3
```

and i want to get this result :

```
tran                 loc

111                  0    

222                  3   

333                  5
```

I think it is supposed to be done by partition function but I don't know how...any help please?

Comment: Your result could be achieved by selecting TRN and LOC and then grouping on them with a GROUP BY.

Comment: Is there always a one-to-one relationship between TRN and LOC?

Answer (score 3):

```
select t.trn, t.loc 
from (select trn, loc, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY trn, loc ORDER BY trn, loc) as rnum
from table ) t
where t.rnum = 1
```

Or you can use `RANK()` function instead of ROW_NUMBER(), rest of syntax is same.
http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/rank.php